# Use not equal to in sql query

Tags: php, sql

I want to select all values that does not have a zero from the db using.  But in this case I am getting all values with a zero too

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name <> value
```

How do I get to use `<>` in the above query and achieve what I require.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one select every row where colum_name **is not** value.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name <> value
```

This one select every row where colum_name **does not have** value in it. Is that your problem ?

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name NOT LIKE '%value%'
```

Comment: As you said 'all values that does not have a zero' perhaps you make a mistake in what you really wants. If not Pavanred give you the correct query !

Comment: Yes, it worked, need to wait another 7 mins before I can accept

Comment: +1 for your amazing psychic mindreading powers to work out what that question was about ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want - returns all values in column_name which are not equal to 0

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name > value (0 -> in this case)
```

that will give you desired results.

Answer (score 0):

`!=` is an operator as well - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Comment: `!=` is not compliant with SQL-92 standard. Stick to `<>` if you want your database to be portable across different SQL engines

Comment: Sorry, thought this question was about MySQL specifically.

Answer (score -1):

```
$countLoad = 'SELECT * FROM stuffing_' . FIN_YEAR .
             ' WHERE gatlID=' . $gatlID . ' AND StuffingID NOT IN' .
             '("SELECT * FROM load_assigned_' . FIN_YEAR . ')';
```